# Can someone help explain how the css3 calc() method actually works?

Tags: css, cross-browser

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

I have been working on a library that converts some css3 methods into css2. One tricky part is math.. The proposal of css3's calc() method pretty much blew my mind..

I am able to add/subtract/divide/multiply pixels from ems or any other fixed unit, but I have no clue how you would add 10px to 60%.

Say you have variables setup: $width1 = 10px; and $width2 = 50%;

```
width: <?php echo $width1 + $width2; ?>;
```

Is there any way to perform this kind of math so that static width values can be applied to older browsers? Maybe using css expressions as a fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my best guess, you can't.  That's why CSS3 added that functionality, because CSS2 couldn't do it on its own.  There are several CSS framworks that add that functionality.  As far as unit conversion, you'd have to make some decisions about priority, using your example:

$width1 = 10px
$width2 = 50%

Assuming (for this example) a 500px screen, if percentages takes priority, you'd first have a block that's 250px, to which you add 10px, resulting in 260px.  If you go the other way, it would be 250px. (This is assuming auto takes priority over all, so auto + 10px, then 50% of it's parent container).

Comment: So basically some sort of live calculation of the overall screen width, converted to pixels/ems would be necessary. Bummer.

Comment: Well, percentage doesn't necessarily refer to the overall screen width; it refers to the container.  So if you had one div that was defined to be 400px, and a div within it that was 50%, the inner div would be 200px.

Comment: Yeah, so it's going to be alot of calculations to keep it correct, as soon as you introduce a percentage into the equation, you need to be listening for a resize so if anything does change you can run your calculations again.